# Can the filename of a static library be renamed

Tags: unity-game-engine, static-libraries

I have an Unity3D project and a static library project (.a extension) in Xcode. In both cases I can't change anything in both projects. 
The unity3D project depend on the static library from Xcode but the filename of the static library is different than the filename referenced in Unity3D project.

Can I change the filename of the static library and be sure that Unity3D project will compile?